# My app crashes while making a method of setSupportActionBar( )

Tags: android, crash, toolbar, android-appcompat

I'm trying to create a custom Toolbar on my Activity but at the time I launch the app it crashes The code which I have written for setSupportActionBar is below:

Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

It's asking for creating a method of setSupportActionBar and below error is coming out

D:\AndriodSDK\LcitNewDemo\app\src\main\java\com\lcit\lcitnewdemo\SetActivity.java:23: error: incompatible types: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be converted to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

When I try to create a method of setSupportActionBar(), it's showing this error in Logcat which I have mentioned below

Here is a Logcat

```
--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.lcit.lcitnewdemo, PID: 4372
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.lcit.lcitnewdemo/com.lcit.lcitnewdemo.SetActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to 
android.widget.Toolbar
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3356)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3500)
at 
android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks
(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at 
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at 
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar cannot 
    be cast to android.widget.Toolbar
    at com.lcit.lcitnewdemo.SetActivity.onCreate(SetActivity.java:22)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7973)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3500) 
    at 
    android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.
    java:83) 
    at 
    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks
    (TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute
    (TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
    (RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
    I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4372 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Imported android.widget.Toolbar change to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml if you are using "androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar" then import

"import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar"

Similarly if you are  using android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar then import in your java file

"import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;"

Comment: You should not use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar. Its no longer being supported. Stick with to using androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Use `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`(seems it's deprecated & no longer supported.):

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     />
```